# magento2 admin panel product edit page Quantity text field is disabled for bundle product

Tags: magento2

Magento2 admin panel product edit page Quantity text field is disabled for bundle product..

Please tell me how can i make enable this text box.

Answer (score 1):

> As per my understanding Bundle Product is Always depends on Simple
>   Products which you assign to that Bundle Product.

**Bundle Product is a group of simple product. So its Quantity is depends on The products which you are assign in to the bundle product.**

**The bundled product doesn't have an inventory qty by itself, but it's saleability is determined by its required bundle options**

**So if you want to edit the Quanitity of bundle product , you need to go with the specific simple product which you have assigned to bundle product and increase that simple product Quantity**

**It will automatically increase bundle product Quantity.**

> So not only on admin product edit page but also on add new bundle
>   product page , the Quantity box is disabled.

Comment: Hello,I am managing the Qty on bundle level not on simple item level.
Some time Quantity Text field is enable sometime disable...this is the problem..I want this enable all time.
Please help

Comment: From Where you are managing ? have you done any customization on that ?

Comment: Hi,
I am checking the qty of bundle only on front end for shopping.
My Problem is only Admin Panel=> Product Edit page for Bundle=>qty field text box some time shows enable some time disable .
If i select the bulk updation of qty and put qty this is working. Indivual Bundle edit for Qty not working

Comment: @TaslimWaris I can understand that , are you doing bulk updation of only bundle products ? or its mixture of simple and bundle products ? Because Quantity of bundle products is always disabled